# string array from c# to javascript example not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i'm using asp.net web form fx3.5 and i'm trying to get my server-side string array into my javascript. i found a simple example that claims to work but it doesn't for me. temp variable is not recognized in ().Serialize(temp);

[Here's the reference article](http://forums.asp.net/post/4352050.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ShelterExpress.UserInterface.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server" language="c#">
    string[] temp;
    int lengthOfTemp;

    public string tempJSON = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(temp);
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's in the temp variable? Null? How do you serialize null?

Comment: Have you tried initialising temp to some dummy data? It may well be erroring as temp hasn't be initialized

Comment: Is this a JavaScript question? I don't see any JavaScript. (JSON isn't JavaScript.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script runat="server" language="c#">
    string[] temp;
    int lengthOfTemp;

    public string tempJSON;

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)//you have to initialize your temp and tempJSON in a method
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        temp = new string[] { "Hi", ",", "ojlovecd" };//Initialize your temp here
        tempJSON = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(temp);
    }

</script>
```